# Project in eclipse works fine but file .jar its not

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, deployment

I launch my app in eclipse and works fine and I got the initialization of de entityManagerFactory by default as I wish:

```
2022-11-28 13:32:58.558  INFO 12176 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

but when I deploy my app by a runnable jar file it is not launching, I'm sharing this question after much research, here is my pom (I'm extracting the libraries into generated jar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>ZpectrumApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ZpectrumApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZpectrumApp</name>
    <description>End-Degree project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec-javase</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>ZpectrumApplication.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I thinks it is possible a incompatibility from one spring-boot version to another dependency, but I'm not certain. Also attach the console trace.

```
ZpectrumApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#71a9b4c7' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#71a9b4c7': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Comment: Please don't post picutres. But include the whole stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by deploying the project by command prompt in the next three steps:

- downloading Apache-Maven https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
- following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ARoNTL90hY
- modifying the pom.xml with manual configuration -> https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven

Answer (score 0):

You have to build and package the jar with dependencies, add the below to your plugins in the pom.xml, change the main mainClass to yours.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
         <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>single</goal>
               </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
         <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.byteworks.epms.DeviceServiceListener</mainClass>
            </manifest>
         </archive>
         <descriptorRefs>
             <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
         </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```